# CSS3 transition shows scroll bar instead of the content of the tag

Tags: css

I have created a transition effect for a menu on a web site. When I hover over the element it doesn't show the content that I want to see. Instead of that, scroll bar appears. This means the transition effect is working on this menu but the page doesn't go up to show the menu content. 
My menu is at the bottom of the page. Please see My code below. Thanks

```
 .change_height { 
overflow:hidden;
height: 20px; 
transition: height 3s;
}
.change_height:hover
{ height: 198px;  }
```

Comment: Please show an example of the full source code (incl. HTML) on a website or even better on something like jsfiddle.net

Comment: Works fine [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6wm2/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS alone, even with animations will not cause the browser to automatically scroll. You'll need to use JavaScript that's triggered on hover.

From a usability point of view I wonder why you'd want the menu to appear in that position? If the element that triggers it is always at the bottom of the page why not have it animate upwards?